# rMBP Late 2013 crash without log and have to restart by power button

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, google-chrome, crash, performance

I bought rMBP around November last year.
As I open Chrome, it crash without log.
I can't move the mouse, and the mms stream player keep working.

The only solution is to restart it with power button.

I can't find the report by chrome://crashes and ~/Library/Logs/.

I think the kernel_task doesn't make it.

Are there anyone else got the same problem and solution?
How to identify the unexpected shutdown by power button in shutdown_monitor.log or /var/log/system.log?

Version:10.9.1(13B3116)
Chrome Version 32.0.1700.107

Comment: Look at /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports. You can do it using Finder or Utilities>Console app.

Comment: There isn't any log in it. I am trying to find the reason in the system.log or shutdownmonitor.log.

Comment: I seem to have similar problem. There's no log at all. The system just freeze like you describe with the display still on. I think it happens since I install Mavericks and for me, it persists even after I completely (format and repartition) reinstall the OS. I've been reaching out to Apple support but they haven't found any problem and just assume that some of the apps I install, including Chrome, cause the problem. The apps, which are almost my daily usage, were okay before that so I'm quite confused. The crash happens not constantly but about few days to 10 days once.